# Como ver a implementação de uma função?

Tags: c

De vez em quando tenho algumas dúvidas quanto a eficiência de um código e penso que se eu ver a implementação de uma função que eu esteja utilizando eu possa saber o quanto é eficiente ou não.

Alguns exemplos de implementações que iria sanar algumas dúvidas:

1) Qual a implementação de `<=` ou `>=`? Quais as diferenças em relação ao `<`, `>` e `==`? A comparação `>=` seria duas funções separadas ou uma só?

2) Qual a implementação de getchar(), gets() e scanf() ? Qual a diferença entre elas?

3) Qual a implementação do `do..while()`, `while()` e `for()`? Os dois últimos parecem ser a mesma coisa mas de uma maneira diferente de colocar os parâmetros. Seria a mesma implementação? Quão eficiente é utilizar o `for()` em vez de `while()` e vice-versa?

Já li algumas documentações da linguagem C e do compilador, que utilizo, GCC, mas eu gostaria mesmo é de poder ver essas implementações, ou algo muito próximo que pudesse esclarecer estas dúvidas.

Comment: A única maneira é lendo o código fonte do compilador e vendo o que ele gera. Mas pra uma resposta rápida: 1) muito provavelmente cada uma dessas será uma única instrução de máquina, todas com o mesmo desempenho; 2) não faço ideia; 3) depende muito da arquitetura na qual o programa é compilado, mas não deve ter diferença significativa. O mais comum é `se a condição X for falsa faça um desvio pra instrução A` durante o teste e `faça um desvio incondicional pra instrução B` ao final do loop. Já num `do..while` não há esse último desvio, e a condição é testada no final (por verdadeiro nesse caso).

Comment: +1 pro comentário do mgibsonbr. E para os operadores matemáticos, acho que é mais interessante ver como eles funcionam a nível de hardware.

Comment: Mais uma pergunta. Onde eu encontro o código fonte do GCC ? Encontrei vários sites com versões "releases" mas não sei em qual eu posso confiar. Grato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Editando aqui, complementando a resposta original que segue abaixo:** A implementação dessas funções e operadores é uma coisa bastante complexa, e se você é iniciante recomendo não se estressar com isso agora. Assuma sempre que as implementações das linguagens de baixo nível são as mais eficientes possíveis. Querer saber como essas coisas funcionam é uma das marcas do bom programador, mas até você dominar técnicas de construção de linguagens e compiladores, é mais importante conhecer os algoritmo e o uso correto dessas funções do que sua implementação propriamente dita.

---

A implementação das funções da linguagem é separada da linguagem em si ;)

Comparações de maior ou menor, tipo `a > b`, podem ser feitas de formas diferentes por processadores diferentes. O ARM do seu celular pode fazer isso de um jeito, ao passo que o i3/5/7 do seu PC pode fazer de outro. Mas uma linha de código como:

```
if (a < 3) { /* .. snip .. */ }
```

... Deve funcionar em ambos.

Então qual é o segredo? Cada processador possui uma linguagem de máquina (assembly) própria. C, C++ e outras linguagens de baixo nível são uma forma de você expressar comandos para a máquina, mas no final das contas o compilador pega o que você escreveu e traduz pra linguagem de máquina do processador para o qual está compilando.

Pra ficar mais engraçado ainda, dois compiladores diferentes podem gerar código assembly diferente para o mesmo código fonte de entrada.

E pra ficar mais e mais engraçado ainda - como o compilador é escrito pra funcionar em um sistema operacional, as próprias bibliotecas do compilador - que contém esses métodos - podem variar de um sistema operacional pra outro.

Se você quer ver a implementação dessas funções, a forma que eu sugiro é ler o código fonte dos compiladores e das bibliotecas do C.

Eis a fonte das bibliotecas do C pra GNU: http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.20/files.html

Lá você encontra, dentre outras, a [scanf](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.20/scanf_8c_source.html) e a [printf](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.20/printf_8c_source.html), como implementadas pro Linux. Note que a parte onde ele trata a arquitetura alvo ainda fica por baixo disso, então boa escavação ;)

Comment: Aproveitando que falou de documentação, onde posso encontrar todas as documentações do GCC e C originais ? Tanto como implementações de funções e coisas do tipo ? O link que passou ( http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.20/files.html) já é o original ? E este link que encontrei: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf é o original da linguagem C ? Grato.

Comment: Não sei quanto ao link que você passou aí, mas o link que eu passei é o oficial. O primeiro link no topo da página te leva para a página central do compilador, com links para [a documentação](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/documentation.html).

Answer (score 4):

> Qual a diferença entre `getchar()`, `gets()` e `scanf()`?

getchar lê um caracter de cada vez, gets lê uma linha inteira de cada vez e scanf é uma função genérica que faz coisas diferentes de acordo com o a string de formatação que você usar. Essas funções fazem coisas bem diferentes e é melhor escolher a mais apropriada ao invés de se preocupar com micro otimizações (o custo de fazer operações de entrada e saida e chamadas ao sistema operacional é provavelmente muito maior do que .

---

Para o resto das suas perguntas, sugiro que você aprenda a ler os arquivos executáveis gerados pelo seu compilador. No caso do gcc você pode usar a flag -S para obter uma versão em assembly language do executável gerado do seu programa:

```
gcc -S meuprograma.c -o meuprograma.S
```

O compilador tem bastante liberdade para alterar a estrutura do seu programa, desde que o resultado seja o mesmo do original. Acho que você vai se surpreender com o resultado em alguns casos :) Só uma dica: para simplificar as coisas, escreva só uma função com o código de seu interesse - deixe de lado a entrada e saida.

Vale notar, que isso tudo depende do compilador que você usa, do nível de otimização (-O0, -O1, -O2) e da arquitetura do seu processador (x86, x86-64, ARM, etc)

> 1) Qual a implementação de <= ou >= ? Quais as diferenças em relação ao <, > e == ? A comparação >= seria duas funções separadas ou uma só ?

Não se preocupe com isso. O seu processador provavelmente vai gastar o mesmo tempo pra qualquer uma dessas comparações e mesmo que fosse diferente, o seu compilador provavelmente ia dar conta de fazer as microotimizações ele mesmo (por exemplo, um  `if(a < b){ XXX }else{ YYY }` é o mesmo que um `if(a >= b){ YYY }else{ XXX }`).

> 3) Qual a implementação do do..while(), while() e for() ? Os dois últimos parecem ser a mesma coisa mas de uma maneira diferente de colocar os parâmetros. Seria a mesma implementação ? Quão eficiente é utilizar o for() em vez de while() e vice-versa ?

É tudo igualmente eficiente. o seu compilador vai converter todos as estruturas de controle estruturadas (if, while, for, etc) em um grafo de fluxo de execução de mais baixo nível e no final vai cuspir uma sopa de `goto` não estruturada.

---

Só um aviso para suas aventuras: é muito difícil adivinhar quanto tempo o computador vai levar para fazer cada operação e é ainda mais difícil prever de antemão qual parte do seu programa é a que é mais sensível em termos de performance (não adianta nada dobrar a velocidade de um trecho responsável por 1% do tempo total de execução). Sempre use um profiler para ter medidas empíricas do tempo gasto e lembre-se que a CPU não executa todas as operações na mesma velocidade (por exemplo, hoje em dia a velocidade de acesso a memória tende a ser um bottleneck muito maior que o número de operações feitas pela CPU)

Comment: Queria poder dar +1 extra pelos dois últimos parágrafos.

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo a 1º questão:

Não tem diferenças na questão de implementação, possivelmente o comparador >= ou <= "exercem a função" de 2 comparadores, pois primeiro verifica se o valor em questão é igual e depois verifica se o valor é maior ou menor.

Respondendo a 2º questão:

A função GETCHAR() lê um caracter e retorna um inteiro que é: 
- o código do caracter, ou
- o valor -1 que corresponde a fim de ficheiro.

A função GETS, da biblioteca padrão do C (stdio) pode gerar um grande problema para o programador que a usa: como essa função não limita o número de caracteres a serem lidos da entrada padrão (stdin), pode haver vazamento de memória, ou até pior, injeção de código malicioso no programa.

A solução é usar FGETS, que limita o buffer de leitura.

A função usada para efetuar a leitura de valores "genéricos"(recebe qualquer tipo primitivo) é a função SCANF.

Respondendo a 3º questão:

WHILE X FOR:

O FOR executa um numero limitado e fixo de passos, já o WHILE pode fazer isso indefinidamente.

Por exemplo, se eu faço um laço for pra somar 1 a uma variável, já declarada, n vezes, o laço será executado sempre n vezes. O resultado inicial e final serão sempre os mesmos.

Já o while deve ser usado quando é o usuário quem vai definir o valor inicial dessa variável, e o controle serve apenas pro valor máximo.

Sendo mais claro(Exemplificando):

O programa declara, no inicio, x como 1. E depois executa o FOR(laço) 10 vezes, e em cada uma delas o valor será acrescido de 1. O resultado final será sempre 11.

Se for um laço WHILE, escrito pra que essa variável x chegar a 10 (while x<=10), o resultado máximo será sempre 10. Mas se o usuário colocar x inicialmente como 9, o resultado será 10. E o laço só será executado 1 vez.

Se o programa for fixo, sem intervenção do usuário, o mais indicado é o for. Por exemplo, um programa que sempre forneça os quadrados dos números inteiros de 1 a 10.

Mas se for um programa que calcule os quadrados dos números inteiros dentro de um intervalo definido, e digitado, pelo usuário (de x a y, por exemplo), o while é mais indicado.

DO WHILE X WHILE:
A estrutura de repetição DO WHILE parte do princípio de que deve-se fazer algo primeiro e só depois comparar uma variável para saber se o loop será executado mais uma vez.

RESUMO:
O FOR é mais simples de ser implementado, o que pode reduzir um pouco os erros que o programador possa cometer.
A rapidez depende do tamanho do laço, e não há uma diferença significativa entre eles, considerando um numero igual de execuções. O FOR apresenta mais parâmetros,ou seja, mais recursos do que o WHILE, pois além do comparador(que tanto WHILE E FOR possuem),o FOR possui a inicialização de uma variável e o incremento dela.

O WHILE pode ser implementado em funções que executam um numero indefinido (inicialmente) de passos. Portanto, pode ser mais rápido, se o usuário definir uma quantidade pequena de passos. Se for um numero fixo de execuções, é mais simples usar um for.